# If we know nilpotent matrix $N\neq 0$, and $PN\neq 0$ for some idempotent matrix $P$, with the property $PN=NP$, can $P$ be unique determined?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence, idempotents

Just as the title:If we know nilpotent matrix $N\neq 0$, and $PN\neq 0$ for some idempotent matrix $P$, with the property $PN=NP$, can $P$ be unique determined?

(nilpotent means $N^k=0$ for some $k$, idempotent means $P^2=P$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take$$N=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix},\ P_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix},$$and $P_2=\operatorname{Id}$. Then $N$ is nilpotent, $N\neq0$, $P_1$ and $P_2$ are idempotent, $NP_1=P_1N\neq0$, and $NP_2=P_2N\neq0$.

Comment: Okay...but I want to know if $N\neq 0$, is it possible that $P$ is unique?

Comment: @HeHe No. Take $$N=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$and $P$ *any* matrix of the form$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&a&b\\0&0&c&d\end{pmatrix}.$$Then $N$ is nilpotent and $PN=NP$.

Comment: But then $PN=0$

Comment: @AbishankaSaha I've edited my answer.